# Is the word "by" being used as a preposition or adverb in "Sort by extension"?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, parts-of-speech

In the short sentence "Sort by extension.", is the word *"by"* being used as a preposition or an adverb?

When I [look it up in an English dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/by), one of the examples inclines me to think it's being used as a preposition:

> 2. With the use or help of; through: We came by the back road.

Is it, in fact, being used as a preposition, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes: "by" is a preposition with the noun "extension" as its object. The PP "by extension" then functions as an adjunct expressing how something is to be sorted.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks Bill.  If you're rather sure of the accuracy of your comment, feel free to post it as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: Answer posted, as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [1] *Sort* [*by extension*].
>
> [2] *We came* [*by the back road*].

In these examples "by" is a preposition functioning as head of the bracketed PPs (preposition phrases).

In [1] the PP is an adjunct expressing how something is to be sorted.

In [2] the PP is a complement of "came". PPs expressing path are complements because they
have to be licensed (specifically permitted or required) by a verb of motion like "come"